# Adobe Livecycle data services coaching

Tags: apache-flex

I would like to know about the LCDS. What it does? How to configure it? Do I need to know Java?

Can I get some sort of tutorial pdf for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am a new flex developer.I would like
>   to know about the LCDS. What it does?

One of the major feature of LCDS is it provides a server side push implementation to your flex app. 
How to configure it? Would not know, since it does not work in sync with c# have not explored it as much as I would have liked.

> Do I need to know Java?

Yes, unfortunately Java is the major player in supported language, else I would be all over it.

Adobe® LiveCycle Data Services ES is a powerful solution for creating data-intensive rich Internet applications (RIAs) that integrate with J2EE applications and business logic.
That is from the adobe site: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=lcds26_td

> Can I get some sort of tutorial pdf
>   for it?

Best way is to go through the tutorials on the adobe web pages. If you are using hibernate here is an extra example. http://blog.comtaste.com/2007/07/livecycle_data_services_and_hi.html and http://iamjosh.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/building-a-livecycle-data-service-application/
T

Comment: You may want to check out Fluorine FX which includes most of the features in LCDS for the .NET platform: http://www.fluorinefx.com/

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to the great world of Flex. One thing is for sure - your going to enjoy it.

It is always good to satrt with the official site: [http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/dataservices/](http://gregsramblings.com/2008/12/12/livecycle-data-services-and-tour-de-flex/)

if you want to see what can be done with Flex in general and with LCDS, install Tour-de-flex: http://gregsramblings.com/2008/12/12/livecycle-data-services-and-tour-de-flex/

This [Blog](http://weblog.cahlan.com/2008/01/flex-now-livecycle-data-services.html) was a good start point to new guys where I work. 
The most important suggestions he made was to:
1. Get to know google 
2. Check out this [lynda](http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourse.aspx?lpk2=335) course.

**Last but not least, AdobeTV**  have great videos to watch! see: [AdobeTV Data services search page](http://tv.adobe.com/#se+Data%20services)

By the way, AdobeTV itself is fully build with Flex.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure what LCDS can do for you with respect to Coldfusion and Flex/AIR.

There is likely something there that will save you a great deal of time, money and coding.